# Replacing a specific key in a nested dictionary without affecting other keys

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, nested, key

Working on a particular feature of finding and replacing an incorrect key for a sample music dictionary, I'm unable to find the right code to do it.

```
my_dict = {
    1: {
        "Artist": "Pat Metheny",
        "Album": {"Offramp": {"Year": "1982"},
                  "First Cicrle": {"Year": "1985"}}
    },
    2: {
        "Artist": "William Ackerman",
        "Album": {"Imaginary Roads": {"Year": "1986"},
                  "Passage": {"Year": "1979"}}
    },
    3: {
        "Artist": "John Coltrane",
        "Album": {"A Love Supreme": {"Year": "1960"},
                  "Ballads": {"Year": "1966"}}
    }
}

add2dict = {}

def fix_case(x):
    x = ("".join([a if a.isupper() else b for a, b in zip(x, x.title())]))
    return x


def repl(rep):
    index = int(rep[0])
    for d, g in my_dict[int(rep[0])].items():
        if rep[1] in g:
            print('found it')
            print(my_dict[int(rep[0])]['Artist'])
            my_dict[int(rep[0])]['Artist'] = rep[2]
            print(my_dict)
        elif rep[1] in my_dict[index]['Album'].keys(): #check 'Album' keys for rep[1]
            print('found it in ', my_dict[index]['Album'])

            for alb, year in my_dict[index]['Album'].items():
                if alb == rep[1]:
                    my_dict[index]['Album'] = rep[1][year]

            print(my_dict)

        elif rep[1] in my_dict[index]['Year']:
            print('found it')
            my_dict[int(rep[0])]['Year'] = rep[2]

            print(my_dict[1])

        return


ndx2 = 1

keys = []
while True:

    def printData():
        for d, g in my_dict.items():
            print(f'ID: {d}')
            print('Artist:', g['Artist'])
            print("Albums:")
            for album, metadata in g['Album'].items():
                year = metadata['Year']
                print(f'-{album} ({year})')
            print()


    ndx2 = 1
    choice = int(input("1:Add an entry:\n2:Replace an entry\n3:quit or <ENTER>\n:"))
    if choice == int(1):
        Add_dbase = input('Add an entry: ')
    elif choice == int(2):
        printData()
        dbase_repl = input('Enter ID followed by \'/\' and \'old word\'/\'replace word\'')
        repl_keys = dbase_repl.split("/")
        print(my_dict[int(repl_keys[0])].items())
        repl(repl_keys)
        printData()
        break
    elif choice == int(3) or "":
        print("Nothing entered. Bye.")
        break
    else:
        break
```

In my function **def repl(rep)**, handles a situation to change an album key. I pass the Artist index, misspelled key, and correct key as 'rep[0]', rep[1], rep[2] respectively. In the first elif block, I can narrow down the correct key but can't find the right code to change it without affecting the other album key. For example, the album 'First Cicrle' is spelled incorrectly and I want to change it to 'First Circle'. I tried using .replace, .update, .pop and many combinations but I'm not getting only that key name changed. Any ideas please? Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to maintain the ordering of the dictionary keys?

Comment: Don't use the album names as dictionary keys. Doing it that way requires you already know the album's name before you can retrieve it. Make the albums a list of dictionaries instead, each with a `name` key.

Comment: @Vishakha Lall, I'm not concerned yet about the ordering yet. Just need to be able to replace an album name for now would suffice.

Comment: @kindallThe album titles are already in a list of the 'Album' key.  if there's an example what you mean? Much appreciated.

Comment: @cpsharp you need to change key name based on keywords search? For example:  find: `First Cicrle` and replace with `First Circle`, where both are variables?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi, yes it's a keywords search but I can specify which artist key it's in instead of iterating through the entire artist dictionary. I input the string 
'1/first cicrle/first circle' which is split into a list, then I can narrow down the Artist, then I want to replace the specific album key. But the methods I used aren' working for me. in my 'repl' subroutine.

Comment: @cpsharp you need to get entire dictionary as output or just selected by artist key?

Comment: Hi @ZarakiKenpachi. The output only has to be the artist key. Just as long as I know the key has been updated. Nice answer, though it's very rigorous for me. I'll examine it more.

Comment: @cpsharp for single output remove top loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to check every key and dictionary value to find specific phrase.
Then update dictionary data based on changed key values.`replace` list contains: [artist_id, old_key, new_key ]

```
data = {
    1: {
        "Artist": "Pat Metheny",
        "Album": {"Offramp": {"Year": "1982"},
                  "First Cicrle": {"Year": "1985"}}
    },
    2: {
        "Artist": "William Ackerman",
        "Album": {"Imaginary Roads": {"Year": "1986"},
                  "Passage": {"Year": "1979"}}
    },
    3: {
        "Artist": "John Coltrane",
        "Album": {"A Love Supreme": {"Year": "1960"},
                  "Ballads": {"Year": "1966"}}
    }
}


replace = [1, 'First Cicrle', 'First Circle']

for k, v in data.items():
    if k == replace[0]:
        out = {}
        for key, value in data.get(replace[0]).items():
            if key == replace[1]:
                out[replace[2]] = value
            else:
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    value3 = {}
                    for key2, value2 in value.items():
                        if key2 == replace[1]:
                            value3[replace[2]] = value2
                        else:
                            value3[key2] = value2
                    out[key] = value3
                else:
                    out[key] = value
        data[k] = out
```

**Output:**

```
{1: {'Artist': 'Pat Metheny', 'Album': {'Offramp': {'Year': '1982'}, 'First Circle': {'Year': '1985'}}}, 2: {'Artist': 'William Ackerman', 'Album': {'Imaginary Roads': {'Year': '1986'}, 'Passage': {'Year': '1979'}}}, 3: {'Artist': 'John Coltrane', 'Album': {'A Love Supreme': {'Year': '1960'}, 'Ballads': {'Year': '1966'}}}}
```